# Spark simple copy-job out of memory

Tags: scala, apache-spark, out-of-memory

I have a simple Spark Job that simply reads a text file and writes it to another using saveAsTextFile. Sounds simple enough.

```
sc.textFile("src.csv").saveAsTextFile("dst_path")
```

Only thing is Spark runs to a particular task and then stalls. I saw a huge spike in kernel_task on my **local pseudo-distributed** mode activity monitor. And finally, it fails with out-of-memory error in like 10 hrs.

Configuration:

- RAM: 8G
- SSD
- InputFileSize: 14G
- driver-memory: 5G
- Processor: 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5

What am I missing? I am guessing it has to do something with the garbage collector. From what I read was Spark reads and streams the records. So why would it try to store it in RAM in this case when there are no transformations?

PS:
Why am I using spark to copy? Not important. I tried a complex job. But the problem boiled down to accessing huge file only.

Comment: Are there stages in between the textFile and saveAsTextFile or is the problem occuring for this exact pipeline (referring to the PS)?

Comment: It is happening in this exact pipeline.